# Passing IHttpClientFactory to .NET Standard class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-standard-2.0, httpclientfactory

There's a really cool `IHttpClientFactory` feature in the new ASP.NET Core 2.1
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HttpClientFactoryForTypedHttpClientInstancesInASPNETCore21.aspx

I'm trying to use this feature in my ASP.NET Core 2.1 Preview-2 app but I need to use the `HttpClient` in my class libraries which are in .NET Standard 2.0

Once I perform `AddHttpClient` in `ConfigureServices()` in `Startup.cs`, how do I pass this `HttpClientFactory` or a specific named `HttpClient` to an API client I created in my .NET Standard 2.0 class library? This client pretty much handles all the API calls I make to a third party.

Basically, I'm just trying to get the specific named `HttpClient` into my `thirdPartyApiClient`.

Here's my code in `ConfigureServices()`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Create HttpClient's
    services.AddHttpClient("Api123Client", client =>
    {
         client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api123.com/");
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    });
    services.AddHttpClient("Api4567Client", client =>
    {
         client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api4567.com/");
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, your library class' constructor should take an `HttpClient` param, so you can inject an `HttpClient` into it. Then, the easiest method (mentioned in the link article as well for what it's worth) is to simply add a specific `HttpClient` for that library class:

```
services.AddHttpClient<MyLibraryClass>(...);
```

Then, of course, register your library class for injection, if you haven't already:

```
services.AddScoped<MyLibraryClass>();
```

Then, when your library class is instantiated to be injected into something, it too will be injected with the `HttpClient` you specified for it.

Alternatively, you can manually specify an `HttpClient` instance to inject via:

```
services.AddScoped(p => {
    var httpClientFactory = p.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    return new MyLibraryClass(httpClientFactory.Create("Foo"));
});
```

Comment: Update: `AddHttpClient` already handles the registration of the service for you in this scenario. You may get an error if you do it in the above approach. 

Refer: https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/1079

Answer (score 38):

Nowadays there is a NuGet package `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` offering the IHttpClientFactory to .NET Standard 2.0

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Comment: This also works for .NET Standard 2.1. Thanks @MichelZ

Comment: Lifesaver! The docs were saying it was part of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` which I already had installed.